# How to get a standalone python script to get data from my django app?

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning how to use django. I have a standalone python script that I want to communicate with my django app. However, I have no clue how to go about doing this. My django app has a login function and a database with usernames and passwords. I want my python script to talk to my app and verify the persons user name and password and also get some account info like the person's name. How do I go about doing this? I am very new to web apps and I am not really sure where to begin.

Some Clarifications: My standalone python program is so that the user can access some information about their account. I am not trying to use the script for login functionality. My django app already handles this. I am just trying to find a way to verify that they have said account.

For example: If you have a flashcards web app and you want the user to have a program locally on their computer to access their flashcards, they need to login and download the cards from the web app. So wouldn't the standalone program need to communicate with the app to get login information and access to the cards on that account somehow? That's what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why does it need to use a stand-alone app? Why not [just use a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/) to query the DB using [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/)? Also, what have you tried - as there are a number of ways to perform this (regex, external libraries, jquery with websockets) and showing your attempt will help people answer you.

Comment: It is just so the user has the option to access their information locally as well without having to go to the web app. I have tried a little research and ran into some things called AJAX and JSON, but I am unsure if this is route I should be going. Sorry, I am very new to web apps.

Comment: "It is just so the user has the option to access their information locally" - A user cannot access this information locally, since it is stored on the server. You can hide it all you want, but you will always have to make an HTTP request to the server to retrieve the information. You might as well do it the easy way and create an actual page on your website.

Comment: "you will always have to make an HTTP request to the server to retrieve the information." This is what I am trying to do. I rather learn how do it though. I am just trying to retrieve information. I am not sure how to do that in my python program.

Comment: If I understand correctly then you need to have an API architecture that is  REST API google about "django rest framework" it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to have an external program communicate with your server.  To do this, the server needs to expose an `API` (Application Interface) that communicates with the external program. That interface will receive a message and return a response.

The request will need to have two things:

- identifying information for the user - usually a secret key - so that other people can't access the user's data.
- a query of some sort indicating what kind of information to return.

The server will get the request, validate the user's secret key, process the query, and return the result.

It's pretty easy to do in Django.  Set up a url like `/api/cards` and a view.  Have the view process the request and return the response. Often, these days, these back and forth messages are encoded in JSON - an easy way to encapsulate and send data.  Google around with the terms `django`, `api`, and `json` and you'll find a lot of what you need.